# How to join two tables and update them in symfony 1.4 Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a system which consist of two user types Seeker and Owner.

**User** table:

- f_name
- l_name
- email
- password
- username

**Seeker** table:

- telephone
- geneder
- address
- Dob

and **Owner** table:

- company_name
- designation
- gender

What I want to do is to join these two table and perform update and read the details of each seeker and owner by id ?

Comment: Do you have a `schemal.yml` or you only asked for us to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

not sure which version of doctrine symfony 1.4 uses. but assuming it to be doctrine 1.2 here is what you can do.

NOTE: always remember in doctrine the tables are referenced as classes.

to select using DQL.

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('User u')
    ->leftJoin('u.Seeker s')
    ->leftJoin('u.Owner o');
$result = $q-> fetchArray();
```

the above query will fetch all the related records, if you want to fetch only the specific values from columns, you can use `select()`

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('u.f_name, u.l_name, u.email, u.password, u.username')
    ->from('User u')
    ->leftJoin('u.Seeker s')
    ->leftJoin('u.Owner o');
$result = $q-> fetchArray();
```